# Make an external vue component responsive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, responsive

I'm using an external script for a live tv component in Vue, but for a reason, I can't make it responsive. Actually, I'm trying to use media queries but I don't know why it isn't working. Up until now, my code is as follows

```
<template>
  <div>
    <myflixtv-player
      channel="channel-test"
      playerWidth="900"
      playerHeight="700"
    ></myflixtv-player>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Live",

  data() {
    return {};
  },

// Run external script for player
  mounted: function() {
    let externalScript = document.createElement("script");
    externalScript.setAttribute(
      "src",
      "https://myflixtv.com/js/myflixtv-player.js"
    );
    document.head.appendChild(externalScript);
  },

  created: function() {},

  methods: {},

  computed: {},

  components: {}
};
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .myflixtv-player {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
```